# Techniques of overcoming ennui (boredom)

Tags: existence, existentialism

Did any philosophers discuss overcoming ennui/boredom?

I read [this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/193/what-philosophical-views-are-there-on-the-problem-of-boredom) and its answer, but I am less interested in a definition of boredom and more interested in direct approaches or theories that aim at removing it.

Comment: Outside of “find something interesting to do”, what exactly are you hoping for in terms of an answer here...? Is there anything specifically you think philosophy might have to suggest here?

Comment: I thought there might be some philosopher who might have approached it in a less dismissive fashion... I'm reading The ontology of boredom now and I'll quote: "but boredom is the challenge to find anything worthy of interest," I thought that if so many philosophers spent time describing it they might have thought of some ways to conquer it.

Comment: David Foster Wallace (who did academic philosophy before going on to the literary world) wrote about boredom extensively (both philosophically in essays and thematically in his novels and short stories). I'd recommend reading his book *The Pale King*, it is entirely about how to understand and deal with boredom. It is a huge theme in *Infinite Jest* of course, but he also discusses it in a non narrative way in his essays "This Is Water" and "*E Unibus Pluram*".

Comment: Perhaps philosophy is the product of ennui therefore philosophers are using their products as cure -- like the effect is the cause, the cause the effect; a point defines a location, a location pointed by the point. 囧

Comment: You are asking to address a symptom, not a disease.
For the symptom, if it itches, scratch it. Find something to do. Young people seem to think the answer to boredom is to find pleasure. Pleasure is not the answer, it exhausts fast and causes you to delay the solution, and your lifetime is limited.
For the disease, you can read Theodor Adorno, Free Time.

Comment: Kierkegaard's pseudonym A in *Either/Or* looks at boredom and how to avoid it in the section called "Crop Rotation". There's also some Sartre on boredom (and specifically ennui) somewhere in *Being and Nothingness*.

Comment: boredom can also be a symptom of depressed mood if you aren't finding any enjoyment in things and not doing anything about it other than complaining.  do something different or learn something new. practice your skills.Improve yourself. Help someone.  learn a new instrument.  talk to a therapist maybe. meditate on it. Write something.  Read a book.  Research something. discover something. Create something. set some new goal at the gym to lose weight or gain muscle or something. Travel somewhere. There are countless things to do.